# Calculating distance with geosphere::distGeo() within dyplr::mutate()

Tags: performance, dplyr, geospatial, geosphere

There is a data frame of about 240e6 rows with combinations of coordinate points between **pseudonym** and **pseudonym2** (**long**, **lat**).
It looks like the following:

```
geo <- data.frame(
  pseudonym = c("aa", "bb", "cc"),
  long_pseudonym = c(9.37, 7.37, 9.86),
  lat_pseudonym = c(52.22, 51.58, 53.48),
  pseudonym2 = c("ee", "ff", "gg"),
  long_pseudonym2 = c(9.69, 8.37, 9.24),
  lat_pseudonym2 = c(51.22, 53.58, 50.48),
  dist_km = NA_real_
)


geo

   pseudonym  long_pseudonym  lat_pseudonym  pseudonym2  long_pseudonym2  lat_pseudonym2  dist_km
1  aa         9.37            52.22          ee          9.69             51.22           NA
2  bb         7.37            51.58          ff          8.37             53.58           NA
3  cc         9.86            53.48          gg          9.24             50.48           NA
```

My first idea was to caluclate the column **dist_km** within a **dplyr::mutate()** with **geosphere::distGeo()**

```
geo <- geo %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dist_km = distGEO(
    p1 = c(long_pseudonym, lat_pseudonym),
    p2 = c(long_pseudonym2, lat_pseudonym2)) / 1000
  ) %>%
  ungroup()


geo

   pseudonym  long_pseudonym  lat_pseudonym  pseudonym2  long_pseudonym2  lat_pseudonym2  dist_km
1  aa         9.37            52.22          ee          9.69             51.22           113.
2  bb         7.37            51.58          ff          8.37             53.58           233.
3  cc         9.86            53.48          gg          9.24             50.48           337.
```

So far, so good.

For small tables this approach is working but for big tables (240 million rows) it is very time consuming.

Does anyone has an idea to do it better?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to

```
geo <- geo %>%
  mutate(dist_km = distGEO(
    p1 = cbind(long_pseudonym, lat_pseudonym),
    p2 = cbind(long_pseudonym2, lat_pseudonym2)) / 1000
  )
```

and it works very well.
For 240 million rows it took less than 8 minutes.
The trick is the **cbind** command before **distGeo**.